# Can you conduct electricity through a banana peel?

Tags: electricity, conductors

While grabbing a banana for breakfast today I got zapped due to static electricity building up while I was moving on my chair, but the conductor I was grabbing was said banana.

Is it possible to conduct electricity through a banana?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just happened to have a multimeter and a banana handy when I read this.  For what it's worth the measured resistance for the outer skin of a dry banana was off the scale i.e. over 20 MΩ.  With a wet banana the resistance measured roughly 1 MΩ fluctuating quite a bit with the way the probes were touching the fruit.  This is less the resistance of my finger measured in the same way.